# Not able to get backcolor of textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, colors, textbox, client-side

I am setting color of a textbox at client side using

```
id.style.backgroundColor = decode[1];
```

Here decode[1] contains colors depending on a condition.

I am able to set the color here, but i am not able to identify this color at server side.

What property should i use to retrieve this color.

`TextBox.BackColor` doesnot seem to work.

As of now I am setting text also in same way and i am able to retrieve the text at serverside but not color.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve this color at server side do one thing you can set this color value in Hidden field and then can get hidden field value from server side which would be same as background color of text box.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I had used hidden field for around 16 fields, so if a get a propery, the work around time would be saved.

Comment: Yes if you take hidden field with id="hdnbgColor" then on server side you can get value with hdnbgColor.value  , I am not sure this is what you need... please let me know if need any help

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such a `property` or `method` that reflect changes made on `DOM` (client side). Try to change `BackColor` at server side.

Comment: On click of textbox i have a popup. One click of any cell in popup, it picks the cell color and sets it to the textbox backcolor.

Comment: @RMN Is it possible to postback when popup cell is selected?

Comment: Do we have any option if it is possible ? Say on text changed event.